# jQuery alternate table row colors for a specific table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two tables. `<table id='1'></table>` and  `<table id='2'></table>`. When i put this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //for table row
  $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
  $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");

});
```

Both the tables got it alternate row colors, which i dont want, i want only to color the table with id=2. how it can be accomplished?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Modify your code like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("table#id2 tr:even").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
  $("table#id2 tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
});
```

This assumes you have table with `id` set to `id2` eg:

```
<table id="id2">
```

Comment: using IDs like that is not allowed in HTML, and IE doesn't recognise it.

Comment: the use of an element selector with an ID selector is extra work on the selector engine (and browser for css) - elements should be specified for classnames only, such as '#id1 tr.myCoolEvenClass'. (in the above example #id1 already points to the table, so no need to say 'look at all the tables and find #id1)

Comment: @nickf: Yup I knew that but i was just extending his example although i should have suggested not use pure number as id. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

First thing is that [it's not allowed to have an id starting with a number](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-id). Change the tables to have ids something like this:

```
<table id="table1"></table>
```

Then, all you need to do is add the right [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) into your jQuery:

```
$("#table2 tr:even").css(...);
$("#table2 tr:odd").css(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Pass your table Id as parameter:


settingTableRowColor('tableid');

var settingTableRowColor = function(tableName){
    $('#'+tableName+' tr:odd').attr('class','odd');
    $('#'+tableName+' tr:even').attr('class','even');
}
```

Comment: TypeError: settingTableRowColor is not a function you have to declare the function first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tab1 tr:odd").css('background-color', 'red');
```

also works